# An enum switch case label must be the unqualified

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

I have encountered an error while trying to execute "mvn prepare-package" for my project.

The console says

> StageManager.java:[96,30] an enum switch case label must be the unqualified name of an enumeration constant

After some research on the internet, I found threads like these:
[Java: using switch statement with enum under subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161408/java-using-switch-statement-with-enum-under-subclass)
or [Why can't an enum value be fully qualified in a switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764874/why-cant-an-enum-value-be-fully-qualified-in-a-switch-statement)
Which aren't useful for me, because I don't have the problems, which causes the exceptions in this examples. My Code looks like this:

StageManager (where the error occurs):

```
for (MessageType item : MessageType.values()) {
    switch (item) {
        case CSVImport:
            //Do some magic
            break;
        case EOWImport:         // <- Line 96 where the error occurse
            //Do some magic
            break;
    }
}
```

Parts of the Enum "MessageType":

```
CSVImport("CSV-Import", -1, Void.class),
EOWImport("EOW-Import", -2, Void.class),

private MessageType(final String description, final int id, final Class<?> klasse) {
    this.description = description;
    this.id = id;
    this.klasse = klasse;
}
```

And I don't understand, why I'm getting this error, because in my opinion, I'm doing it right.

Comment: EOWImport.getId() would fix problem; item.getId() in switch

Comment: Perhaps you would like to post a [mcve].

Comment: But CSVImport is working, EOWImport doesn't, whats the different between them?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you give an MCVE?

Comment: Might be, the code is not the one being compiled. Because you get this error if having a qualified enum constant - like `MessageType.EOWImport`. This code looks fine. So, please, make an MCVE!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Problem was, that I was using a loacal Version where the switch-case Statement was right, but mvn prepare-package was using an external version of the StageManager, where the siwtch-case was wrong, sorry to bother you